# How to create the following JSON dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have an array as shown below

var someData = ["123", "456"];

I am trying to create the following JSON from the above

```
[{
    "link_video": "123",  
     "video_id":456 
}, {
    "link_video": "456"
   "video_id": "123"
}]
```

I have tried the following

```js
var myvideos = [];
var someData = ["123", "456"];
for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
  myvideos.push({
    "link_video": someData[i],
    "video_id": someData[i],
  });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(myvideos));
```

But the output being formed is

```
[{"link_video":"123","video_id":"123"},{"link_video":"456","video_id":"456"}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/465/

Could you please tell me how to form this JSON correctly

Comment: The first "JSON" you quote is not valid json, as it misses a comma after  '    "link_video": "456"'. The second json you get as output IS valid, and as far as i can see, completely the same apart from that one comma. I'm not sure what's wrong with that output?

Comment: the link_video and video_id are same .

Comment: @Nanne Compare the first output to the desired output. Notice that the `link_video` and `video_id` are the same in the generated output, but not the desired one. Also, I'm guessing the invalid JSON in the desired output is simply due to a typographical error.

Comment: @pawan You need to do some computational "magic" on `i` in either of the `someData[i]` statements. Exactly how you should do that we can't really tell you without more input data about the pattern you want to follow (i.e. should it traverse the list in reverse, take the item before `i`, or some other order).

Comment: @BenM ah! i was blindish ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to access two elements in the array for each iteration, so you should update your loop and then append the object twice by accessing the element at index `i` and its immediate sibling in the array:

```js
var myvideos = [];
var someData = ["123", "456"];

for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i+=2)
{
    myvideos.push({
       "link_video": someData[i],
       "video_id": someData[i+1],
    },
    {
       "link_video": someData[i+1],
       "video_id": someData[i],
    });
}
console.log(myvideos);
```

Comment: This works as long as there are an even number of items in `someData`, if it's an odd number the last element is ignored.

Comment: @fredrik But the example provided means that there must always be an even number in the input.

Comment: @BenM I do not see that stated anywhere, do you? Sure, the example only has two elements, but it doesn't say it always will have only two, or even always have an even number. Assuming such things is what usually leads to undefined behavior (or outright bugs) later on. I'm not saying you're wrong, but there's a possibility that the code you provided will give a result the OP actually wasn't expecting under some circumstances. And I think that any and all readers should be made aware of that fact.

Comment: @BenM I still maintain the position that there is too little information in the OP question to draw the conclusion that he has not intended it to be used with more values than 2, or with an odd number of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try his, it might be what your looking for

It also with with more data like `["123", "456", "789"]`

```js
var myvideos = [];
var someData = ["123", "456"];
for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
  myvideos.push({
    "link_video": someData[i],
    "video_id": someData[(i == 0 ? (i + 1) : i == (someData.length - 1) ? (0) : (i + 1))],
  });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(myvideos));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just manually like this lol

```js
var myvideos = [];
var someData = ["123", "456"];

console.log(JSON.stringify([{"link_video": someData[0], "video_id": someData[1]}, {"link_video": someData[1], "video_id": someData[0]}]));
```